# PySpark SQL in Databricks: How to extract names from tables that have similar names?

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks

I have the following tables:

```
Table_A     Table_B    Table_C   List_A
```

Table_A:

```
Column_A             Column_B     Column_C     Column_D
1/1/2020             30           400000       Table_A
2/1/2020             35           200000       Table_A
```

Table_B:

```
Column_A             Column_B     Column_C     Column_D    
1/1/2020             50           4000         Table_B
2/1/2020             70           10000        Table_B
```

Table_C:

```
Column_A             Column_B     Column_C     Column_D
1/1/2020             3            300          Table_C
2/1/2020             5            200          Table_C
```

List_A:

```
Column_A             Line_E                    Column_D       
1/1/2020  09:30:00   30                        List_A
2/1/2020  09:31:00   28                        List_A
```

I want to select all columns from tables that have similar names. In this example, they are `Table_A, Table_B, Table_C`. And their names begin with "Table_".

How to do it?

I tried `spark.sql("SELECT * FROM * where Column_D like 'Table_*'")`, but it does not work.

Comment: Purely in SQL, you can't. You need to write code to gather the list of tables, then write code to write the SQL unioning the tables together.

Comment: @MatBailie I can't write something like `select * from tables where tables like 'Table_%'` ? I expect this kind of things.

Comment: SQL is strongly and statically typed. Those tables could have different column names, different data types, etc. You as the programmer have to handle all of that. Also, SQL is Structured Query Language, it's for Structured data, its in the name. If you know in advance which tables to combine, write a view with UNION ALL combining the tables. If you don't know in advance, you're using Semi Structured data, and need to write code to handle the consequences.

Comment: There are thousands of tables that have similar names. It is impossible to hard code which tables should be included. But what if they have the same column names?

Comment: As per my first comment, you can't do this purely in SQL. You need to write code that queries the list of tables, then writes new SQL (termed Dynamic SQL), then runs that programmatically generated SQL. How are you running your SQL?

Comment: @MatBailie How about adding a new column?

Answer (score 0):

Tables with similar names - are they tables that:

- all start with `Table_`?
- all start with the same prefix of length 5?
- all start with the same prefix followed by an underscore?

Consider table names like `Table_A`, `Tablerone_B`, `Table_bable_C`, `Table_D_D` - similar or not...?

With SQL you can get the list of tables using `SHOW TABLES`, but it is not possible to run it in a subquery, so you are not able to further process it using SQL. But you can use Scala or Python.

```
spark.sql("show tables").select("tableName").as[String].collect.groupBy(_.split("_")(0))
```

This returns `Map(list -> Array(list_a), table -> Array(table_a, table_b, table_c))`

Then you can obtain column names by iterating on above result and running `DESCRIBE <table_name>` - again you need to think what you want to get (all column names? shared column names?)

Comment: Yes. All tables that I want to extract start with `Table_`, have the same prefix of length 5, and have `_`.         `Table_A` and `Table_D_D` are similar.       I only use Pyspark SQL

Comment: I know how to use Spark SQL to extract column names from tables that have similar names. but there is no such thing `SHOW TABLES LIKE "Table_*"` in Python Spark SQL.

Comment: That's exactly why you need DataFrame API for a filter like this.

Comment: I did. I called  `spark.sql`, but it doesn't work.